# Should I use Spring's TaskScheduler to execute a task at a specified time with the @Async annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I am using Spring 3 in a web application and I want to run a task once two minutes into the future (e.g. send an email).  There may be multiple calls to schedule this same task by different users (with different parameters) so there will be some scheduling queue overlaps.

Elsewhere in the application I am using Spring's **@Scheduled** annotation to perform a cron style task at regular intervals so I already have [Spring's task execution and scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/scheduling.html) configured and working.  Therefore my **applicationContext.xml** file contains something like:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor  id="myExecutor"  pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

I've written the following code as a test and from the output sent to the console it doesn't appear to make any difference whether I use the **@Async** annotation or not (the behaviour is the same).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long inXseconds = start + (1000 * 10);        
    Date startTime = new Date(start + 5000);
    TaskScheduler taskscheduler = (TaskScheduler) ctx.getBean("myScheduler");

    System.out.println("Pre-calling " + new Date());        
    doSomethingInTheFuture(taskscheduler, startTime, "Hello");
    System.out.println("Post-calling " + new Date());    

    while(System.currentTimeMillis()< inXseconds){            
        // Loop for inXseconds
    }        

    System.exit(0);
}

@Async
private static void doSomethingInTheFuture(
       TaskScheduler taskscheduler, 
       Date startTime, 
       final String attribute){
    // Returns a ScheduledFuture but I don't need it
    taskscheduler.schedule(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(attribute);
            System.out.println(new Date());
        }            
    }, startTime);                        
}
```

Some my question is:

**Should I use the @Async annotation and what difference will it make if I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference in your case because you have annotated a static method with @Async annotation - and Spring will not create a proxy in this instance.

If you had declared an @Async annotation on a normal Spring bean method, then the behavior would be to internally wrap it up into a Runnable class and submit it as a task to a threadpool, and your called method would return immediately - while the task is scheduled to be executed by the threadpool.

Comment: Thanks Biju.  So would it be kind of analogous to double escaping a string? E.g. spawning a thread to spawn to another thread

Answer (score 0):

As I understood this, the only difference if you put annotation scheduler will execute this task and go to another. If execution of task takes more than your interval (2 minutes) - you will see difference.

With @Asunc annotation scheduler will start new task without waiting previous one to complete. Without this annotation it will wait until current task complete.

So difference can be if task execution takes more than your interval (2 minutes).